# Liberar Campo após data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ola 
Preciso de um código javascript no qual terei dois campos um com a data e um  Descrição  que será desbloqueado de acordo data indicada e bloqueie o anterior
**Exemplo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A Partir do dia 06/06/2018 
o campo anterior é bloqueado e desbloqueado o campo seguinte**
e assim sucessivamente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Desbloquear Campo Após Data</h1>
<div class="row">
              <div class="bs-example align-content-md-center">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Datas</th>
                      <th>Prazo</th>
                      <th>Campo</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong>Data 1</strong></td>
                      <td><div class="input-group enable-calendar">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data1" mask="00/00/0000" value="05/06/2018" readonly>
</div></td>
                      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="descricao1" name="descricao1" placeholder="Descrição" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong>Data 2</strong></td>
                      <td><div class="input-group enable-calendar">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data2" mask="00/00/0000" value="06/06/2018" readonly>
</div></td>
                      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="descricao2" name="descricao2" placeholder="Descrição" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong>Data 3</strong></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="data3" id="data3" value="07/06/2018" readonly></td>
                      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="descricao3" name="descricao3" placeholder="Descrição" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual a duvida, não entendi?

Comment: Preciso de um codigo js que desbloqueie o campo de acordo com a data, exemplo dia se for dia 05/06/2018 o campo estará desbloqueado, apos essa data ele bloqueará o campo. Editei o a pergunta, vê se ajuda.

Comment: O que já sabe de JavaScript? O que tentou fazer? Por quê não deu certo? Apareceu alguma mensagem de erro? Qual? Se não, apenas gerou um resultado indesejado? Qual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você vai precisar pegar o valor que está sendo mudado ou ser a data atual ai depende de você, quando o formulário estiver carregado (ponha isso no header  :

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#data1").change(function() {
         var data1 = document.getElementById("data1").value;
         // faça o seu IF aqui com a condição
         document.getElementById('descricao1').readOnly = false;
        });
       });
```